# How to wait for onReceive to finish while in same thread?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a BroadcastReceiver registered in the UI thread that grabs some information from the Bundle in its onReceive method. I need these values before I proceed in my main thread.

Is there any way to wait for the onReceive to finish before trying to use those values? I am running into timing issues where onReceive sets the values AFTER I try to use them. Having the thread sleep doesn't work, since they're on the same thread.

Would it make sense to register the receiver in an AsyncTask, and call wait() on the main thread, then have onReceive notify() once it completes?

```
String a = "hi";
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(MY_CUSTOM_INTENT);
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Set the variable values here
        a = "bye";
    }
};
getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

// Get the values, I am getting a = "hi" here because the onReceive code has 
// not been reached yet
// How can I guarantee that a = "bye" from this method?
getA();
```

where method is something like

```
String getA() {
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be over-complicating things.  It's hard to know what you're really after based on the example code, but the code that comes after `registerReceiver()` should just do whatever else it needs to do and then return, without waiting for or hoping for the Broadcast to have been received.  `onReceive()` should include whatever code you want to have executed at that point (which may well just be a method call, e.g. `updateA("bye")`.

Comment: Basically, I have other methods that rely on the values set in onReceive, so even though I'm dependent on the receiver, it doesn't really make sense to put that code inside onReceive. I'd like some way to "wait" until the receiver sets those values.

Comment: @nicobatu You either put that code in `onReceive()` or in a method that `onReceive()` calls. That's jut how it works. You don't get to "wait" on the UI thread, but you *do* get to set up a callback to run whatever code you want when the time is right. If you're still having trouble, post a more complete code example. In the example that you gave, the solution is to move the call to `getA()` to be inside `onReceive()`, and you'll have the behavior you want. Obviously you think there's some reason you can't do this in your situation, so post more code.

Comment: I am writing library functions where getA()'s value may change depending on whether the receiver is enabled (by user choice) or not, so I was worried about when the two methods are subsequently called. But I think I will just add a new function where getA() is inside onReceive() for that case.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your going to block the main thread either way, might as well do it elegantly.. Register the receiver with the `AsyncTask`, and use a [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) to let the user know what you are doing or that you are loading something.